# Unable to login to my remote OSD Ubuntu

Tags: login, password, authentication

When I am trying to login to my Ubuntu I am getting message `Sorry, password authentication failed`. But I've been using the same password for the past month, also I used the key <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> in OSD health check, it shows `System health is not ok`. In login LOOP issue it shows as:

```
chown: invalid user: xxxx
settings user permissions for user home directory: /home/xxxx failed
```

Comment: Is this a remote machine? Are you the admin of that machine?